# Jetpack Compose reversed column

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I need to create a column with a reversed order, meaning that given the items

```
Column {
    A
    B
    C
}
```

It renders:

```
C
B
A
```

I see that `LazyColumn` can do this with the `reverseLayout` param, but I can't find anything for the regular `Column`. Has anyone figured out how to do this? I'd rather not have to create a custom layout.

The reason I'm doing this is I'm creating a generic Modal component where the footer buttons switch to a vertical column at small widths. According to our design system, positive actions should go at the top of the column. Generally, this is the last item in the source order, hence my need to reverse the list.

Comment: Why don't you call the child composables in the order that you want? IOW, if you want C-B-A, why are you calling A-B-C? I feel like we're missing some piece of the problem.

Comment: I'm building a responsive modal where the buttons switch to vertical. I suppose I could make the ModalFooter component accept an array of content instead of a single content param, but that doesn't feel as clean as doing a standard content param like `content: @Composable () -> Unit`

Answer (score 1):

Since your'e using column, you can simply reverse the backing structure

```
val items = listOf("Apple", "Banana", "Cherry", "Dogs", "Eggs", "Fruits")

// or
// val items = remember { mutableStateListOf("Apple", "Banana", "Cherry", "Dogs", "Eggs", "Fruits") }


ReversedColumn(items = items.reversed()) // reversed
```

Sample composable

```
@Composable
fun ReversedColumn(items: List<String>) {

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
    ) {

        items.forEach {
            Box(modifier = Modifier
                .height(80.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .border(BorderStroke(Dp.Hairline, Color.Gray)),
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = it
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just reverse the list before passing it to Column for displaying? As per Kotlin docs, you can do it like this:

```
fun main() {
val list = (1..5).toList()

val reverse: List<Int> = list.reversed();
println(reverse)
}
```

I know your question is asking for something else, but I thought this might be helpful.